# implicit conversion from a class to any one of its direct or indirect base classes

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

this is the MSDN's idea about implicit casting .
Implicit conversions: No special syntax is required because the conversion is type safe and no data will be lost. Examples include conversions from smaller to larger integral types, and conversions from derived classes to base classes.
but I'm wondering how casting from derived class to base class is possible because the derived class has more members than it's base class so it is bigger and it doesn't make any sense to me how this is possible?sorry for bad English.

Comment: So what if it's bigger?

Comment: i mean what will happen to those extra members in derived class?

Comment: Classes are reference types so a variable of type `Subclass` is the same size as one of type `BaseClass`. In the case of a struct type being assigned to a variable of type object, the struct is boxed and a reference to the boxed object is stored in the variable.

Comment: so reference types are just like pointers?

Comment: Yes, kind of. But you can't do pointer arithmetic or other unsafe stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra members are still there. No data is lost. You just can not access them from a variable of the base type. This behavior is a property of polymorphism.

When you implicitly (or explicitly) cast `Derived` to `Base`, you are not creating a new instance of `Base`, or altering the existing instance of `Derived`, you are simply creating a different view to `Derived`, treating it *as if* it were a `Base`.

To access the derived members again, you will need to explicitly cast back to a derived type to access them.

Assuming `Derived` has field `Foo` while `Base` does not:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
Console.WriteLine(d.Foo);

Base b = d;
Console.WriteLine(b.Foo); //compile error

Derived d2 = (Derived)b; //or Derived d2 = b as Derived;
Console.WriteLine(d2.Foo); //valid
```

Comment: You can also do it using `Derived d2 = b as Derived;`. The difference here is that using the `as` keyword will return null if the casting fails because of a Type mismatch. Using `Derived d2 = (Derived)b;` will throw an exception if the casting fails. If you want to determine if a Type inherits from a base class, you can use the `is` keyword. `if (d2 is Derived) { // Do stuff }